# How to get bluetooth serial port status under linux?

Tags: linux, bash, bluetooth, console, rfcomm

Getting status of serial ports (ttyS*) via linux terminal is simple:

```
sudo cat /proc/tty/driver/serial
```

Then it shows `serinfo` with list of all uarts with info about status and buffers. When I call

```
sudo cat /proc/tty/drivers
```

then I can see that rfcomm drivers are available:

```
rfcomm   /dev/rfcomm   216 0-255 serial
```

And, of course, reading data comming from paired bluetooth device is not a problem.

The question is: how to get status of rfcomm serial ports (e.g. Blueotooth SPP devices)? Is this information available somewhere in the `/proc` directory like for ttyS* or could I use totally different way?

Comment: Your question is more suitable for [Unix&Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

It depends what status you are looking for. The "rfcomm" command that comes with bluez does have some status info. It depends if that is adequate for you.

```
% rfcomm -h
RFCOMM configuration utility ver 4.101
Usage:
        rfcomm [options] <command> <dev>

Options:
        -i [hciX|bdaddr]      Local HCI device or BD Address
        -h, --help            Display help
        -r, --raw             Switch TTY into raw mode
        -A, --auth            Enable authentication
        -E, --encrypt         Enable encryption
        -S, --secure          Secure connection
        -M, --master          Become the master of a piconet
        -f, --config [file]   Specify alternate config file
        -a                    Show all devices (default)

Commands:
        bind     <dev> <bdaddr> [channel]       Bind device
        release  <dev>                          Release device
        show     <dev>                          Show device
        connect  <dev> <bdaddr> [channel]       Connect device
        listen   <dev> [channel [cmd]]          Listen
        watch    <dev> [channel [cmd]]          Watch
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly `rfcomm` shows very feeble informations, practically only about status of connection (or its lack). I'd like to know about status of rx/tx buffers and overflow error.